# Element styles stripped within jCarousel

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel

I'm having a very odd problem whereby styles of any elements (in this case a `div`) placed within a `jCarousel` `li` are being stripped out.

The class can be seen (Thanks Firebug) but there are no styles attached. All seems to work fine when the styles are listed inline.

I created a **jsfiddle** to try and work out the problem, but it seemed to work as I want it when using that. Here's a link anyway: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielmeade/CWqWP/1/)

Any ideas on what's happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the full code. Can you provide a link to your page or paste everything into the fiddle? Most obvious thing would be to check that your stylesheet is definitely being pulled in to the page (path is correct etc).

Comment: I copied code from your fiddle to html-page on my computer and it works fine. The only thing I did: uncommented `.jcarousel-item` and set `width 257px;` to it

Comment: Thanks, the stylesheet does seem to be pulled correctly as you can see from http://dev.hackerhouse.co (Video's section) I've added some inline styles too so you can see it working in that respect.